# Attach an object to a session variable in JSF 2.2

Tags: jsf

I have a simple question. All my life I have been in the world of .Net and now I am in a Java project, so I feel rookie.

I'm using

- JSF 2.2
- JDK 11
- Eclipse 2019-06

Can I have a session variable that lives only while the connection of that request is active and is not shared by other request / sessions?

I have drivers of type @ViewScoped.

I want to assign from a Controller, for example:

```
Request.IdSomething = 10    
Request.ObjectUser = MyObjectUser; //my entitys
```

I from two other different Controller, from other views / pages, to have access to those variables. This to avoid creating those same variables in all Controllers where I need to "travel" that object.

Can be done?

In production this application will be used with Containers (kubernetes), so I do not want my object to be shared between the different connected users.

The object that I want to travel between Controllers, does not require that the user is necessarily logged into the system.

Greetings and thanks!

Comment: I cannot imagine .Not has the concept of a session scoped varialble that only lives for the duration of a request. That isort of a contradiction in terms. In java we have request scoped variables for this. Every basic jsf tutorial has examples of these

Comment: And I think you effectively have a chooce of conversationscoped, windowscoped or the deltaspike viewaccessscoped. I use the latter frequently

Comment: And your title is misleading for your actual question.